# The page cannot be displayed IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have configured asp.net site in IIS 6.0:

Allow anonymous access = true
Setted host header, directory path, port,ip
in asp.net tab - asp.net 2.0
in web.config added
`<add path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="True" />`
enable default content page = true
permission settings fine
Integrated windows authentication = ture

When I browse it in IIS then I got error

```
<The page cannot be displayed 
The page you are looking for is currently unavailable. The Web site might be experiencing technical difficulties, or you may need to adjust your browser settings. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please try the following:

Click the  Refresh button, or try again later.

If you typed the page address in the Address bar, make sure that it is spelled correctly.

To check your connection settings, click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Options. On the Connections tab, click Settings. The settings should match those provided by your local area network (LAN) administrator or Internet service provider (ISP). 
See if your Internet connection settings are being detected. You can set Microsoft Windows to examine your network and automatically discover network connection settings (if your network administrator has enabled this setting). 
Click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Options. 
On the Connections tab, click LAN Settings. 
Select Automatically detect settings, and then click OK. 
Some sites require 128-bit connection security. Click the Help menu and then click About Internet Explorer to determine what strength security you have installed. 
If you are trying to reach a secure site, make sure your Security settings can support it. Click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Options. On the Advanced tab, scroll to the Security section and check settings for SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, PCT 1.0. 
Click the  Back button to try another link. 



Cannot find server or DNS Error
Internet Explorer
```

`

By the way: on this IIS server are hosted two another asp.net sites and work fine.
I configure new one by analog as these. But my doesn't want to work.

Comment: Can you get actual error? (ie don't show user-friendly in IE).

Comment: Did you check the read/write and execute permissions?

Answer (score 0):

[Setting Up Default Documents (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)

Did you set the default document for your application?

Answer (score 0):

Not so long ago I was facing with such a problem. Go to IIS\Web Service Extentions. Ot the right side check if ASP.NET 2.0 is allowed or not. In our case it wasn't.

Comment: Asp.NET extention is allowed.